# Can a DNS server uniquely identify a specific client device behind a NAT?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, nat

I've been playing around with this Netflix Proxy setup (https://github.com/ab77/netflix-proxy), and I noticed that it might be possible to use the DNS endpoint to function like a hotspot with a walled garden setup to restrict Internet access to only authorized users (since that's how the Netflix proxy essentially functions when you're behind a dynamic IP)

I was wondering if there is any way that a DNS request can uniquely identify a client behind a NAT device that's performing the request? We have certain use-cases where we would like to limit the use of Internet access to authorized persons only, and we would need to identify them from behind NAT devices.

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

No. Not in for DNS and definitly not in the way you want (i.e. not only say "there are 2 machines" but "one of them is allowed because").

NAT hides the IP address. DNS has no markers in the protocol identifying the machine.

On top, under most setups you will never get a client talking to you - the client will log into the NAT device (hotspot) and use this as DNS server - so ALL requests you do not mally get are from the hotspot, NOT via NAT, but via it's own DNS proxy.

For other protocols there may be ways to identify (guess) how many cleints there are (example browsing - different IE identifiers may allow to say that there is more than one machine), but this is guesswork.

But it is irrelevant for DNS, because the standard setup for DNS is not to use NAT for DNS but to proxy it, at least in a small setup. And if that is not happening, DNS via UDP leaves no real traces at all.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, if someone is behind NAT, you won't be able to see more than the public IP connecting to you.

[Some extra info](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/what-is-network-address-translation-nat-and-how-does-it-work/)

Comment: That is not totally true in general - there are means to identify clients at times, depending on the protocol you have access to (worst case: the machine sends the computer name). It is true for DNS though, because the UDP based challenge/response does not offer identifiers. For a TCP connection.... I am not so sure. I remember there being something about identifying machines based on port numbers. A lot of guesswork can allow things to happen.

Comment: Yeah, that's right, I clearly just posted the *easy* answer but of course there are methods of getting info of clients behind it, not sure about how reliable is that tho.

Comment: I would say in most cases the question is wrong to start with - as per my answer. The standard setup (hotspot) will not use NAT for DNS but proxy it and act internally as DNS and DHCP server.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was pretty sure it wasn't the case, but I wanted to make sure. With the whole FCC controversy limiting open firmware, if we're not able to run custom firmware that allows for hotspots on commodity hardware, we're looking at alternatives on how to deploy hotspots for guest wifi.